# Extracting key-value pairs from multiline text in java

Tags: java, regex, key-value

Consider the following multiline string:

```
This is multiline text that needs to be correctly parsed into key-value pairs, excluding all other information.

 Section One:
    First key = Value One
    Second key = Value Two

 Section Two:   
    Third key = Value Three
    Fourth key = Value Four
    Fifth key = Value Five

 Section Three:
    Sixth key = Value Six
    Seventh key = Value Seven
    Eighth key = Value Eight
```

In other words, the text consists of an "introduction" (some phrases), followed by of multiple lines, organized in sections, each of which has a "header" (e.g., `Section One`) and multiple key-value pairs, separated with `=`.

The keys can contain any character apart from new line and `=` and the values can contain any character apart from new line.

At times, other irrelevant lines may appear in the text.

A regex is needed that will cause `matched.find()` to return all key-value pair groups and only those, skipping both the introduction and the section headers, as well as any other line that does not have a key-value pair.

Ideally, no other text preprocessing or post-processing would be required.

Reading the text line-by-line and processing accordingly is not an option in this use case.

Patterns like `(?:\r|\n)(\s*[^=\.]+)\s*=\s*(.+)` come close but they still include a bit more of the requirement.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the spacing is constant, also try `(?m)(?<=^ {4}).+?(?= *= *(.*))`

Comment: The spacing is not constant, it does not work. Thanks though. :-)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about **Reading the text line-by-line and processing accordingly is not an option in this use case.** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there . Just change `\s*` to `<space>*` because `\s` matches newline character also.

```
(?:\r|\n) *([^\n=\.]+)(?<=\S) *= *(.+)
```

If it contain tabs, then change `space*` in the above to `[ \t]*`. `(?<=\S)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a non-space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gL0jQ3/1)

```
String s = "This is multiline text that needs to be correctly parsed into key-value pairs, excluding all other information.\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        " Section One:\n" + 
        "    First key = Value One\n" + 
        "    Second key = Value Two\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        " Section Two:   \n" + 
        "    Third key = Value Three\n" + 
        "    Fourth key = Value Four\n" + 
        "    Fifth key = Value Five\n" + 
        "\n" + 
        " Section Three:\n" + 
        "    Sixth key = Value Six\n" + 
        "    Seventh key = Value Seven\n" + 
        "    Eighth key = Value Eight";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\\r|\\n)[\\t ]*([^\\n=\\.]+)(?<=\\S)[\\t ]*=[\\t ]*(.+)").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Key : "+m.group(1) + " => Value : " + m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key : First key => Value : Value One
Key : Second key => Value : Value Two
Key : Third key => Value : Value Three
Key : Fourth key => Value : Value Four
Key : Fifth key => Value : Value Five
Key : Sixth key => Value : Value Six
Key : Seventh key => Value : Value Seven
Key : Eighth key => Value : Value Eight
```

Comment: Or we can use \s* to include tabs, too.

Comment: that's why i told you to add `[ \t]*`

Comment: Sure. There is an issue with some section headers that are followed by a tab - the regex joins every such header with the first key in the section, for some reason. The first version is simpler and produces the same results with the second. +1 already and thanks.

Comment: Does really \s match newline? My impression is that it does not.

Comment: You are right. Then (?:\r|\n) * can be replaced by \s*.

Comment: but don't know 'if there really a line break exists or not.